# Passing setStateof nested object to child in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a question I've been googling and I can't find an answer. If I have a component (Parent) that has a state using the `useState` hook and another component (child) that I want to pass the setState function to but the state is a nested object how would I do that. For example:

Parent:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent

export default function Parent() {
const [state, setState] = useState({name: '', age: '', height: '', eyeColor: ''})
return (
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <ChildComponent state={state} setState={???}/>
);
}
```

Child:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function ChildComponent({state, setState}) {

return (
     <label htmlFor='nameInput'>Name:</label>
     <input name='nameInput' value={state.name} onChange={(e) => setState???}/>
);
}
```

I know usually if the state was in one component you would do `setState({...state, state.name: 'Jane'})` but I'm not sure how I would pass that kind of `setState` down.

edit: I would like the `ChildComponent` `setState` function to be dynamic so I could reuse the component 4 times for each state value (name, age, height, eyeColor) with the same component maybe passing in a value to change what value is updated?

Comment: why do you store all these values in a single state-object, if you seem to intend to update them independantly of each other?

Comment: I have this working with multiple `setState` hooks for each value. I was just wondering if it is possible to do it in one state-object. Maybe it isn't, in which case I'll continue to use multiple hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way (out of many possible):

```js
export default function Parent() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({name: '', age: '', height: '', eyeColor: ''})
    const change = prop => ({target}) => setState(state => ({...state,[prop]:target.value}));

     return (
         <h1>Title</h1>
         <ChildComponent label="Name" value={state['name']} onChange={change('name')}/>
         <ChildComponent label="Age" value={state['age']} onChange={change('age')}/>
         <ChildComponent label="Eye Color" value={state['eyeColor']} onChange={change('eyeColor')}/>
     );
}

export default function ChildComponent({label,value,onChange}) {

   return (
     <label htmlFor={`${label}Input`}>{label}:</label>
     <input name={`${label}Input`} value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function form of `setState` to gain access to the current state.

`setState` is passed the current state as it's first argument:

```
onChange={(e) => setState(currentState => ({...currentState, name: newName}))}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been more clear , I'll edit my post. How would I do this to make `setState` dynamic so that I can reuse `ChildComponent` 4 times with each value in `state` i.e. name, age, height, eyeColor. From your answer it seems like `ChildComponent` could only ever update the `name` value of `state`.

Comment: this is just an example of how to update `name`. To update other parts of the state follow the same pattern

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from utilising [`React.createContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and [`React.useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass state between components.

From the docs:

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to child) via props, but this can be cumbersome for certain types of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many components within an application. Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree.

Here is an example how context could be used to share state between components n levels deep.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect, 
  createContext,
  useContext
} = React;

const ComponentContext = createContext();

function Parent() { 
  const [state, setState] = useState({name: 0, age: 0});
  return ( 
    <ComponentContext.Provider value={state}>
        <div>Parent</div>
        <Child/>
        <button 
            onClick={()=>setState({...state, name: state.name+1})}>
                Update Name
        </button>
        <button 
            onClick={()=>setState({...state, age: state.age+1})}>
                Update Age
        </button>
    </ComponentContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Child() { 
  const {name} = useContext(ComponentContext);
  return <div>
      <div>1st Child: {name}</div>
      <Child2/>
  </div>;
}

function Child2() { 
  const {age} = useContext(ComponentContext);
  return <div>2nd Child: {age}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <Parent /> , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `setState` just like you pass the `state`.
Parent:

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

 import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent

 export default function Parent() {
 const [state, setState] = useState({name: '', age: '', height: '', eyeColor: ''})
 return (
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <ChildComponent state={state} setState={setState}/>
 );
}
```

Child:

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';

 export default function ChildComponent({state, setState}) {

 return (
     <label htmlFor='nameInput'>Name:</label>
     <input name='nameInput' value={state.name} onChange={(e) => setState(e.target.value)}/>
 );
 }
```